# How to print random imported strings from user in C?

Tags: c, string, random, cs50

The assignment is as follows: Write a program that takes in courses from a user, saves them in an array, and then prints out a random course for user to complete first.

For example:

```
How many courses do you have homework in? 3
Course: Math
Course: English
Course: Computer Science
Math, I choose you!
```

```
// Helps a user decide which homework to do first
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt the user for the number of courses that they have homework in
    int n = get_int("How many courses do you have homework in? ");

    // TODO: Declare an array of courses with the correct number of elements

    // TODO: Prompt the user for their course names and store it in the array
    string courses[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        courses[i] = get_string("Course: ");
    }
    return(0);
    // Initialize random number generator
    // (found info on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    // Find a random number
    int r = rand() % n;

    // TODO: Print out a random course number with index r
    printf("%s/n", courses[r]);
}
```

This is my code above. How do I fix the print statement to print a random string that the user imported?

Comment: You have `return(0)` before the code that prints the random element. That ends the program.

Comment: `/n` should be `\n` in the printf.

Comment: Other than that it looks fine.

Comment: You can lose the variable `t` in your code: `time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));` —— simply use `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` (or use `0` in place of `NULL` — and the cast isn't necessary if you have `<stdlib.h>` included so that `srand()` is declared with a prototype.  This is not a major problem; it is merely a refinement.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a problem in your code, you've put `return (0);` before finishing your work, so your main always exits before printing anything.

- it's a \n not /n.